# Rails object associated with button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hyperlink

```
<% @book.each do |book| %>
 <%= book.title%>
 <%=image_tag book.image_link%>
 <%= book.authors%>
 <%= book.description%>
 <%= link_to 'Book IT' %>
 <%= link_to 'Read IT' %>
 <%= link_to 'Own IT' %>
<% end %>
```

So heres a copy of my code that prints the title, image, and author of a book searched.  I am trying to associate the 'Book IT' link to add that particular object to my "Book it" library/table so that when i click on my 'Book It' Library link it will display that book.

A few other questions.  Should I replace the link with a button? if so will the button be associated with the object through the loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### you can do it with ajax request

```
<%= link_to 'Book IT',add_to_my_books_book_path,remote: true %>
```

routes

```
resoures :books do 
    member do
    get :add_to_my_books
    end
end
```

controller

```
def add_to_my_books
    @book = Book.find params[:id]
    @my_books = current_user.books
    @my_books << @book
    respond_to do 
        format.js {render alert("book added to your books")}
    end        
end
```

i assume that you has one_to_many relationship between users and books